# Генерация всех вариантов строк из 3 текстовых файлов и внесение в массив на C#?

Tags: c#

К примеру, имеем 3 текстовых файла со списками: 
1.txt (Имена), 2.txt (Фамилии), 3.txt (Отчества).

Как генерировать все варианты из строк в этих файлах и внести в массив (в массиве должны быть все получившиеся варианты типа: Имя, Фамилия, Отчество, последовательность такая же, например: Олег, Штольц, Михайлович, а не Штольц, Олег, Михайлович и подобное) и как записать все эти строки из массива в один текстовой файл с делиметром: `;`, к примеру?

Также интересует, как посчитать количество всех получившихся вариантов из массива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string [] names; //имена
string [] lastnames; //фамилии
string [] middlenames; //отчества
//вся эта радость загружается из файликов.
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string name in names)
{
    foreach (string lastname in lastnames)
    {
         foreach (string middlename in middlenames)
         {
              results.Add(name+','+lastname+','+middlename);
         }
    }
}
//Вывод results в какой-нибудь текстовый файлик.
//Следующее для чтения/записи из файлов. Там все просто.
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx
//Для того, чтобы узнать количество элементов в results используем свойство Count
results.Count;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли...

Comment: Я бы только не складывал результат в `results`, а сразу выводил в файл, т. к. результирующий список может быть ОЧЕНЬ большим и съесть всю память. Да и исходные файлы тоже.

Итого:

    IEnumerable<string> GetCombinesNames(string first, string patro, string last)
    {
        foreach (var name in File.ReadLines(first))
        foreach (var patronymic in File.ReadLines(patro))
        foreach (var lastname in File.ReadLines(last))
            yield return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", name, patronymic, lastname);
    }
    File.WriteAllLines("out.txt", GetCombinesNames(...));

Comment: Благодарю за вариант, большое спасибо...